# Cant reference a Folder as Source for ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

basically i have created a folder insde the Drawable Folder called "logo" with a image at different scales, i have seen in different tutorials that you can just reference the folder in the atributte "src" and thats it, you can totally use the view normally, but for some reason i cant do that in here.

i have tried changing the name of the folder but i still have the same problem, plus if i just drop the images inside the drawable folder, i can use them normally...

Thanks for your help !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DARqs.png)

Comment: You cannot create your own subdirectories of a resource directory (e.g., `logo` in your case). "i have seen in different tutorials that you can just reference the folder in the atributte "src" and thats it" -- that has never been supported.

Comment: so how can i organize all my drawable elements ? should i always just drop the images in the drawable folder ? thanks for ur answer mate !

Comment: "so how can i organize all my drawable elements ?" -- I do not know exactly how you intended to use the images at different scales. But, there is nothing stopping you from using naming conventions (e.g., `logo_` prefix on the filename).

Comment: wait, so i could just use the hdpi image for example and i wouldnt have any problem when it comes to the sizes of any device ? i thought that when it comes to images u needed all sizes (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi) sorry for the stupid Question, im just starting in all this

Comment: "so i could just use the hdpi image for example and i wouldnt have any problem when it comes to the sizes of any device ?" -- screen density (e.g., `hdpi`) is unrelated to screen size. "i thought that when it comes to images u needed all sizes (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi)" -- you do not necessarily need to support all densities, as Android can scale images for you from a nearby densites. And, for those that you do support, there are already dedicated directories per density (e.g., `res/drawable-hdpi/`).

Comment: "im just starting in all this" -- the use of drawables (and mipmaps) for various densities is covered in many books and courses on Android app development. For example, I cover them in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).